# Список на CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css, css3, grid

Есть список:

```
<ul class="grid">
<li class="item">item 1</li>
<li class="item">item 2 long</li>
<li class="item">item 3 long long</li>
<li class="item">item 4</li>
<li class="item">item 5 long</li>
</ul>
```

1. Как правильно задать CSS, чтобы список получился горизонтальный с выравниваем по левому краю?
2. Учитывая пункт выше, как правильно прижать последний элемент списка к правому краю?

*P.S.: про флексы знаю, но хочу узнать, как это делают на гридах...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот так:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  height: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "e d c b a";
}

.block1 {
  grid-area: a;
  background: red;
}

.block2 {
  grid-area: b;
  background: green;
}

.block3 {
  grid-area: c;
  background: blue;
}

.block4 {
  grid-area: d;
  background: purple;
}

.block5 {
  grid-area: e;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item block1">Grid Item 1</div>
  <div class="grid__item block2">Grid Item 2</div>
  <div class="grid__item block3">Grid Item 3</div>
  <div class="grid__item block4">Grid Item 4</div>
  <div class="grid__item block5">Grid Item 5</div>
</div>
```